# react-native-notifications not working with @voximplant/react-native-foreground-service

Tags: react-native, websocket, notifications

So I'm using react-native-foreground-service to keep my websocket connection in background and using react-native-notifications to show data from websocket to notification. My websocket doesn't have issues, because my console log showing data message from websocket. But Notifications package didn't show notification and no errors. Here is my code :

```
import { Notifications } from "react-native-notifications";
import VIForegroundService from "@voximplant/react-native-foreground-service";
import config from "./config";

export default async function Notif(){
    await VIForegroundService.getInstance().createNotificationChannel({
        id:"id",
        name:"app_name",
        description:"service",
        enableVibration:false
    });

    try {
        await VIForegroundService.getInstance().startService({
            channelId:"id",
            id:1,
            title:"app_title",
            text:"Listening...",
            icon:"ic_icon",
            button:"Ok"
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
    const ws = new WebSocket(config.ws_url);
    ws.onopen = () => setInterval(() => ws.send("ping"), 60 * 1000);
    ws.onmessage = (e) => {
        if(e.data !== "pong"){
            var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
            console.log(data);
            Notifications.postLocalNotification({
                title:"app_name",
                body:`Received report type ${data.type === 1 ? "Post" : "Comment"} from ${data.from}`
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-push-notification you can use this hope this will help you!!